# How to avoid anchor links from jumping/scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

So I understand that anchors are intended for jumping/scrolling.. but I'm looking for a solution that would help prevent this.

Situation:
I have a sidebar menu with tab functionality. They have assigned anchors, that can be linked to from external links/other pages.

However, when you're on the page - clicking a different menu item causes the page to scroll up/down 50-100px or so.. which is distracting and frustrating as a user.

Is there a way that the anchor functionality can remain when the page is linked to, but when navigating the sidebar menu, there aren't any jumps/scrolls?

Comment: do you mean smooth-scroll? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp

Comment: or an <a href="#">foo</a> ?
this will make the anchor go nowhere

Comment: No sorry for the confusion. The scrolls/jumps work fine.. but I "don't want them to work" (unless it's on page load). 

When clicking the menu links, I don't want any scroll or jumps